# subfig Caption Number is 1a, How to Modify it to 1(a)?

Tags: captions, subfloats

In the following document, the sentence `in Figure \ref{fig:loop}` in the source produces `in Figure 1a` in the output, but I want it to be `in Figure 1(a)`. How do I achieve my goal?

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for this example, remove it
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \begin{document}

    \title{0000}


    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
    X
    \end{abstract}

    \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

    \section{0000}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pic/loop.png}\label{fig:loop}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{pic/twopath.png}\label{fig:twopath}}
    \caption{xx}
    \label{fig:routing}
    \end{figure}

    in Figure \ref{fig:loop}, we have xx

    \end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be loading both the `subfig` and the `subcaption` packages. Since you're already using some `\subfloat` instructions, you should probably not load the `subcaption` package...

Comment: I removed `subcaption`, the result is the same.

Comment: You already have an answer below *without* `caption` nor `subcaption` and producing the desired result. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{listofformat=parens}
```

and use `\subref`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup[subfloat]{listofformat=parens}

\begin{document}

\title{0000}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
X
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{0000}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:loop}} \hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:twopath}}
    \caption{xx}
    \label{fig:routing}
\end{figure}

in Figure \subref{fig:loop}, we have xx

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if it's a good idea to use the `caption` package as you are doing now with the `IEEEtran` class; in any case, `subcaption` and `subfig` are not compatible.